# Refraction or reflection in dermoscopy?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, medical-physics

I was reading a dermoscopy textbook, and I came across the following statement:

> Why do most moles just look brown? The stratum corneum reflects light, reducing the ability to see detail of structures in the underlying skin. Thus most moles look brown, with relatively little detail. The detail exists; it is just not visible.
>
> If we are able to overcome the refractive properties of the stratum corneum, greater detail in the underlying skin can be observed. This is the underlying concept upon which dermoscopy is based. This can be achieved by the simple application of an interface medium directly to the skin, such as alcohol gel. Any bright light source and magnification lens can then be used to see increased detail in the skin, including the morphological detail and pigment distribution within naevi.

The stratum corneum is the outermost layer of the skin.

It seems to me that the author is talking about the *reflective* properties of the stratum corneum -- not the *refractive* properties? Or am I incorrect? If it is a matter of *refraction*, then please explain why this is the case.

I would appreciate it if someone could please clarify this.

---

### **EDIT**:

The authors provide the following solution:

> Dermoscopy devices can simplify the previously described process by combining a bright illumination source and a strong magnification lens in one handheld device. Dermoscopy devices overcome the refractive properties of the stratum corneum either by the use of oil immersion with an interface medium such as alcohol gel or by cross-polarisation.
>   There are consequently three groups of devices:
>
> - Oil immersion devices – which require contact with the skin and the use of an interface medium to reduce surface light scatter.
> - Cross-polarised devices – which use cross-polarised light to reduce surface light scatter.
> - Hybrid devices – which have the option to use either cross-polarised or oil immersion to reduce surface light scatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit a matter of semantics, and some authors will be happy throwing around terms like *refractive* and *reflective* properties somewhat interchangeably. The reason is that *refraction* and *reflection* are intimately related phenomena ultimately described by the same optical constants of the material. That is, you could start with the refractive index ($n$), or the permittivity ($\epsilon$), or the electric susceptibility ($\chi$), or the optical conductivity ($\sigma$), all of which are complex functions of frequency and can be redefined in terms of one another, and then calculate the reflection, refraction, and transmission expected from a particle of such a material. (Of course, things are further complicated for varied and disordered media like skin, but you get the idea).

So basically, when the author says “refractive properties,” she/he really means “linear optical properties,” which includes all the stuff that’s within the scope of your book.

Comment: Great insight! Thank you for this.

Comment: @ThePointer my pleasure. Out of curiosity, does the author go on to explain *why* an interface medium would overcome the refractive properties and reveal deeper structure?

Comment: See my edit. Does that explain it? My understanding is that these methods -- especially oil immersion -- are common techniques in general microscopy.

Comment: Oh, oil immersion is common in microscopy to improve the resolution. But for imaging beneath a scattering layer (such as skin), it can also be helpful to “fill in the cracks” with a liquid to reduce the scattering. I suspect that’s the reason a gel is used in dermoscopy. Scattering happens at interfaces, and filling in the cracks with a refractive liquid like oil or gel can effectively reduce the number of interfaces light encounters.